# Given a string and a string position. Determine if the word is wrapped in a HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this problem where I have a string. When sent off to a service I'm given an array of objects that I need to use to replace words at specified positions within that string. But I want to skip any thing that is returned that is already wrapped in an anchor tag.

For example This string:

```
var str = "<p>Gilbert Arenas is still a <inline id='something0-container' class='something-container linkContainer' contenteditable='false' data-content='ANNOTATION '><inline class='something' id='something0'><div class='something-preview'>" + 
"      <a href='#'>Washington Wizards</a> " +
"</div></inline></inline> fan. The above Instagram photo -- especially the caption -- is evidence of this. The former All-Star guard didn't wait to find out the Wizards' first-round opponent to start talking trash -- both the Toronto Raptors and Chicago Bulls were targets.</p><p>Honestly, though, I'm a little disappointed in this. Dissing the Canadian anthem? Frying bologna? Arenas can do better, I'm sure. Really hope Drake -- or Masai Ujiri, perhaps? -- fires back.</p>";
```

And this object

```
[{
    "canon": "Dakota Wizards",
    "text": "Wizards",
    "begin": "258",
    "end": "265",
}, {
    "canon": "Dakota Wizards",
    "text": "Wizards",
    "begin": "430",
    "end": "437",
}, {      
    "canon": "Toronto Raptors",
    "text": "Toronto Raptors",
    "begin": "495",
    "end": "510",
}, {
    "canon": "Chicago Bulls",
    "text": "Chicago Bulls",
    "begin": "515",
    "end": "528",        
}]
```

I need to determine whether or not the occurance of "Wizards" at position 258 is wrapped in an anchor tag (which in this example it should).

EDIT: Accidently removed spaces when putting string in the first time. Fixed here

Comment: Wouldn´t the word not be in that position since its in a wrap? And that is not a string, you have both double quotes and single quotes inside without scaping

Comment: looks like you can search for `name+"</a>"` to hit it as a string

Comment: Substring of 258 to 265 gives : "ds</a><"

Comment: you will have to parse the string for open/close tags as this is not trivial in general. in simple cases one can do it by simple tricks like look-ahead or look-back, but in general one would have to parse open/close tags to be sure, not trivial

Comment: Is `canon` the replacement string ?

Comment: @juvian Fixed the string. Copied over from the chrome console. Also stackoverflow isn't keeping the whitespace that is showing up in the chrome console. Suffice it to say on my page string.substr(value.begin, value.end-value.begin) for the first object returns "Wizards"

Comment: @guest271314 No it keeps the text. The canon string is used in a tooltip that tells the context of the text. I.e. text can be "Wizards" and canon would be "Dakota Wizards"

Comment: _"When sent off to a service I'm given an array of objects that I need to use to replace words at specified positions within that string."_ What are replacement words ?

Comment: @guest271314 So I could have a string like "Jordan played for the bulls" Then I could be returned and object like {canon: "Michael Jordan", text: "Jordan", begin: 0, end: 5} I would need to replace "Jordan" With a HTML string like "​<inline id='something0-container' class='something-container linkContainer' contenteditable='false' data-content='ANNOTATION '><inline class='something' id='something0'><div class='something-preview'>
    <a href='#'>Jordan</a>
</div></inline></inline>" The next time I need to make sure that I don't inject another html structure into one that's already been set

Comment: @DrewLandgrave See post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```js
var str = "<p>Gilbert Arenas is still a ​<inline id='something0-container' class='something-container linkContainer' contenteditable='false' data-content='ANNOTATION '><inline class='something' id='something0'><div class='something-preview'>     <a href='#'>Washington Wizards</a> </div></inline></inline> fan. The above Instagram photo -- especially the caption -- is evidence of this. The former All-Star guard didn't wait to find out the Wizards' first-round opponent to start talking trash -- both the Toronto Raptors and Chicago Bulls were targets.</p><p>Honestly, though, I'm a little disappointed in this. Dissing the Canadian anthem? Frying bologna? Arenas can do better, I'm sure. Really hope Drake -- or Masai Ujiri, perhaps? -- fires back.</p>"

var arr =  [{
    "canon": "Dakota Wizards",
    "text": "Wizards",
    "begin": "258",
    "end": "265",
}, {
    "canon": "Dakota Wizards",
    "text": "Wizards",
    "begin": "430",
    "end": "437",
}, {      
    "canon": "Toronto Raptors",
    "text": "Toronto Raptors",
    "begin": "495",
    "end": "510",
}, {
    "canon": "Chicago Bulls",
    "text": "Chicago Bulls",
    "begin": "515",
    "end": "528",        
}]

//note that this works if your text does not contain < tags, if it does, you need to modify this a bit

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    subStr = str.substr(arr[i].begin, arr[i].end-arr[i].begin)
    
    if(subStr == arr[i].text){ //matches, lets check if its in an anchor
        indx = str.substr(0, arr[i].begin).lastIndexOf("<") //get last < tag before our text
        if(indx != -1){
            if(str.substr(indx, 2) == '<a'){ //yay its in a <a> tag
                console.log(arr[i].text + " is inside <a> ")                
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I modified your solution below a bit to check if the begin and end indexes fall between the opening tag and the corresponding closing tag. Regardless Thanks for this it got me to the 10 yard line :D

Comment: No problem, and yeah was just giving a hindsight of a way to approach the problem, glad you improved it ;). Good luck with your proyect

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
var str = "<p>Gilbert Arenas is still a <inline id='something0-container' class='something-container' linkContainer contenteditable='false' data-content='ANNOTATION '><inline class='something' id='something0'><div class='something-preview'><a href='#'>Washington Wizards</a></div></inline</inline> fan. The above Instagram photo -- especially the caption -- is evidence of this. The former All-Star guard didn't wait to find out the Wizards' first-round opponent to start talking trash -- both the Toronto Raptors and Chicago Bulls were targets.</p><p>Honestly, though, I'm a little disappointed in this. Dissing the Canadian anthem? Frying bologna? Arenas can do better, I'm sure. Really hope Drake -- or Masai Ujiri, perhaps? -- fires back.</p>";

var data = [{
    "canon": "Dakota Wizards",
    "text": "Wizards",
    "begin": "258",
    "end": "265",
}, {
    "canon": "Dakota Wizards",
    "text": "Wizards",
    "begin": "430",
    "end": "437",
}, {      
    "canon": "Toronto Raptors",
    "text": "Toronto Raptors",
    "begin": "495",
    "end": "510",
}, {
    "canon": "Chicago Bulls",
    "text": "Chicago Bulls",
    "begin": "515",
    "end": "528",        
}];

var res = $.parseHTML(str.slice(data[0].begin, data[0].end).replace(/\//, ""))
         .some(function(el) {
           return el.nodeName === "A"
          });

console.log(res); // `true`
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Close but this only got the "Wizards" from the string so that when you did el.nodeName === 'A' it returned false because it was a text node. @juvian's solution worked below

Comment: @DrewLandgrave Tried stacksnippets, above ? Not return `true` at `console` ?  String "Wizards" was not utilized at `js` , only `begin`, `end` properties of `data` object . String "Wizards" does not appear _"at position 258"_ within string `.some` should not return `false` ; `text` was first node within return value from `$.parseHTML` , `a` elements was second node; `.some` only requires a single item to return `true` . See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: @DrewLandgrave _"I need to determine whether or not the occurance of "Wizards" at position 258 is wrapped in an anchor tag (which in this example it is)."_ `s</a></` appears at position 258-265 of input string _not_  string "Wizards" . _"Close but this only got the "Wizards" from the string **so that when you did el.nodeName === 'A' it returned false**"_ Can reproduce `js` at stacksnippets returning `false` at `res` ?

Comment: Stackoverflow has messed up the formatting on the string. In my chrome console on my page when I run the string.substr(begin, end-begin) it returns "Wizards"

Comment: @DrewLandgrave _"when I run the string.substr(begin, end-begin) it returns "Wizards""_ ? Can create http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?, what is `end-begin` ? Can  _"when you did el.nodeName === 'A' it returned false"_ be reproduced ? Where was `false` returned ?

Comment: False was returned at el.nodeName === "A" because el was the string "Wizards" so el.nodeName returns "undefined" undefined === "A"  = false

Comment: @DrewLandgrave Where ? At stacksnippets ? Can create http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate , reproduce ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DrewLandgrave/d2y5r6uv/1/ Updated the fiddle with the correct HTML string that matches the data object

Comment: I've attached a working fiddle for my solution to my answer below

Comment: @DrewLandgrave The updated string `str` appear different than originally posted string at http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8ba12a92-9ec1-49c8-a989-09772585ef60/view-source ? See http://jsfiddle.net/d2y5r6uv/2/

Comment: the updated string is the correct version. I've updated the string to reflect the actual problem. Stackoverflow reformatted my original string and took out whitespace that made the string match up with the array of objects. You're solution works if the sliced string is an a tag but not if it's just text. I.e. Your solution works if the slice is "s<a></" but if the slice is "Wizards" it returns false

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('a:contains("Wizards")').length){
 //there is at least one instance of Wizards in an <a> tag
}
```

Comment: Thought about this but this wouldn't tell me if it was at the position in the object.

Comment: you mean its at the char number 258 and ends at char 265 of the whole html text?

Comment: Yes. This is for articles and we are running a service that replaces text with links based on predefined criteria

Answer (score 0):

Modified @juvian's answer. Working Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DrewLandgrave/05wz1fLw/

```
/**
 * Checks to see if text is in between a specified tag in a string
 *
 * @param {string}     string       The entire string to search
 * @param {string}     searchString the string you want to determine whether or not it's inside of a tag
 * @param {string}     tagName      The tag name you want to see if your string is in between
 * @param {string|int} start        The beginning string position of the searchString in your string
 * @param {string|int} end          The end string position of the searchString in your string
 *
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
insideTag = function(string, searchString, tagName, start, end){
    start = parseInt(start) || string.indexOf(searchString);
    end = parseInt(end) || start + searchString.length;

    var subStr = string.substr(start, end - start), 
        startTag = '<' + tagName, 
        endTag = '</' + tagName,
        indx;

    if (subStr == searchString) { //matches, lets check if its in a tag

        indx = string.substr(0, start).lastIndexOf("<") //get last < tag before our text

        if (indx != -1) {

            if (string.substr(indx, tagName.length + 1) == startTag) { //yay its in a tag

                return start > parseInt(indx) && (end < string.indexOf(endTag, indx) + endTag.length)

            }
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```